# C++ class use of undefined type

Tags: c++, class

I have a class that I made that I am using in thread above the class. Even though I did a prototype of the class at the top it still throws off those errors
error C2027: use of undefined type 'foo'

```
class foo;

DWORD WINAPI demo(LPVOID param)
{
    foo a;
}


class foo
{
public:
int x;
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Even though I did a prototype of the
>   class

With a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) of the class you can create pointers and references to the class. This is because pointers/references are represented the same across all classes/structs/etc. They're all just addresses of memory. So, for example, you could create a second class that can accept or contains pointers or references before fully defining the class, ie:

```
  class Bar
  {
  private:
      foo* aFoo;
  public:
      Bar(foo* foo2) : aFoo(foo2) {}
  };
```

However, until the compiler sees the full **definition** of the class, you can't  instantiate it. Otherwise the compiler doesn't know how much memory to allocate and how to call the constructor and other methods. In most cases, C++ expects things to be defined before they are used. Forward declaration lets you get around this a little bit because pointers and references for any class are identical. So you can promise to the compiler you'll fully define it later.

Comment: So its impossible to get a class or struct used before its defined in all cases?

Comment: @Anon: Correct. Here's an analogy: a class definition is like a blueprint for objects of a certain type. Without the blueprint the compiler can't possibly know how to generate the code that creates objects of that type. Instantiating objects before its class is fully defined is like building a house without a fully-defined blueprint.

Comment: Yes. How would you expect to use a class before defining it?